Dependencies breaking npm build presumably bringing ES6 code into ES5 compatible legacy build
I'm working on an old, legacy project, to which I had to introduce Highcharts library. Since it was not working with previous version of Canvas I had to upgrade that one to. Those 2 changes were working for some time, but then the build broke, I think with no interaction on my side, however as I'm not an expert in build processes I might be in the wrong here. The only difference in my package.json is this:
dependencies: {
...
+    "highcharts": "^11.1.0",
+    "highcharts-react-official": "^3.2.0",
...
},
devDependencies: {
...
-    "canvas": "^1.3.1",
+    "canvas": "^2.11.2",
...
}

The error I'm getting is happening during prod build, while minifying the code in this line (at least that's what I think):
var cmd = `mkdir -p build && NODE_PATH=${_node_path()} browserify ${_vendor_exports().join(' ')} | NODE_ENV=production envify | uglifyjs -c --keep-classnames --keep-fnames> ${vendor_bundle}`;
_execute(cmd, cb);

and the error is this:
Error: Parse Error: Line 161191: Unexpected token .
    at throwError (/mnt/js/node_modules/jstransform/node_modules/esprima-fb/esprima.js:2818:21)
    at throwUnexpected (/mnt/js/node_modules/jstransform/node_modules/esprima-fb/esprima.js:2880:9)
    at parsePrimaryExpression (/mnt/js/node_modules/jstransform/node_modules/esprima-fb/esprima.js:3592:9)
    at parseLeftHandSideExpressionAllowCall (/mnt/js/node_modules/jstransform/node_modules/esprima-fb/esprima.js:3682:61)
    at parsePostfixExpression (/mnt/js/node_modules/jstransform/node_modules/esprima-fb/esprima.js:3722:20)
    at parseUnaryExpression (/mnt/js/node_modules/jstransform/node_modules/esprima-fb/esprima.js:3789:16)
    at parseBinaryExpression (/mnt/js/node_modules/jstransform/node_modules/esprima-fb/esprima.js:3879:16)
    at parseConditionalExpression (/mnt/js/node_modules/jstransform/node_modules/esprima-fb/esprima.js:3939:16)
    at parseAssignmentExpression (/mnt/js/node_modules/jstransform/node_modules/esprima-fb/esprima.js:4192:16)
    at parseConditionalExpression (/mnt/js/node_modules/jstransform/node_modules/esprima-fb/esprima.js:3945:26)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! js-site@1.0.0 build-vendor-prod: `node scripts.js build-vendor-prod`

[...]

Parse error at 0:13452,4201
:u,destroyObjectProperties:function(t,e,i){k(t,function(s,r){s!==e&&s?.destroy&&
                                                                      ^
ERROR: Unexpected token: punc (.)
    at JS_Parse_Error.get (eval at <anonymous> (/mnt/js/node_modules/uglify-es/tools/node.js:21:1), <anonymous>:75:23)
    at fatal (/mnt/js/node_modules/uglify-es/bin/uglifyjs:300:53)
    at run (/mnt/js/node_modules/uglify-es/bin/uglifyjs:239:9)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/mnt/js/node_modules/uglify-es/bin/uglifyjs:177:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19

Can you help me out with a direct solution, or at least an idea on how can I tackle the issue?

The highcharts and highcharts-react-official libraries do not have any dependencies, so I don't think this is a problem with them. https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts?activeTab=dependencies https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official?activeTab=dependencies

What about highcharts-react-official dev dependencies like browserify, enzyme, babel which are also used by my project, could it be that the versions used don't match and there's some inconsistency ?

But these are still only dev dependencies, the final build of the package does not use them. Maybe the problem here is the incompatibility of the higcharts-react version with the React version? Since this is an older project and the React version is below 16.8+, you should not use version 3+: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react?tab=readme-ov-file#general-prerequisites

Alright so in the end it was an issue with Highcharts bringing in optional chaining in the code, which was a problem for either envify or uglifyjs (browserify was also used in the dev build so I assumed it wasn't causing any issues).
This line helped the most:
Parse error at 0:13452,4201
:u,destroyObjectProperties:function(t,e,i){k(t,function(s,r){s!==e&&s?.destroy&&

as I cloned Highcharts repo, found the line and see that it was committed more or less at that time my build stopped working. To fix the issue I've downgraded to Highcharts v10.3.3, as has it even specified in their ts/README.md file NOT to use optional chaining.
This doesn't fix my build, as it's still not compatible with ES2020+ code (I was thinking it's not compatible with ES6) but at least that was a solution to fix my problem.
